# Create lookup column in pandas based on content of cell in dataframe, from a differently named column in a different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have tried

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="inner", on="UserID")
```

But that doesn't work.

I get a KeyError, but I'm not even entirely confident that will give me the right answer. Won't that just lay the data from the second column next to the first, unsorted, when actually I want some kind of per-cell lookup to determine which UserID corresponds to which Email and Name?

I have this df

| ObjectID | UserID | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ajh1 | john123 | Strawberry1 |
| Basd2 | katie456 | Orange1 |
| Chg3 | sarah789 | Pumpkin1 |
| Eas1 | john123 | Strawberry2 |
| Fjd3 | sarah789 | Pumpkin2 |
| Gar2 | katie456 | Orange2 |
| Dfd4 | emilio012 | Melon1 |
| Ddfd5 | emilio012 | Melon2 |

And this one

| ObjectID | Email | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| katie456 | katieATkatieDOTcom | Katherine Smith |
| emilio012 | emilioATemilioDOTcom | Emilio Perez |
| john123 | johnATjohnDOTcom | John Muller |
| sara789 | saraATsaraDOTcom | Sara De La Cruz |

And what I want is

| Object ID | User ID | Description | Email | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ajh1 | john123 | Strawberry1 | johnATjohnDOTcom | John Muller |
| Basd2 | katie456 | Orange1 | katieATkatieDOTcom | Katherine Smith |
| Chg3 | sarah789 | Pumpkin1 | saraATsaraDOTcom | Sara De La Cruz |
| Eas1 | john123 | Strawberry2 | johnATjohnDOTcom | John Muller |
| Fjd3 | sarah789 | Pumpkin2 | saraATsaraDOTcom | Sara De La Cruz |
| Gar2 | katie456 | Orange1 | katieATkatieDOTcom | Katherine Smith |
| Dfd4 | emilio012 | Melon1 | emilioATemilioDOTcom | Emilio Perez |
| Ddfd5 | emilio012 | Melon2 | emilioATemilioDOTcom | Emilio Perez |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can do (I'm supposing the `sara789` in the `df2` should be `sarah789`):

```py
out = (
    df1.merge(df2, left_on="UserID", right_on="ObjectID", how="left")
    .rename(columns={"ObjectID_x": "ObjectID"})
    .drop(columns=["ObjectID_y"])
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
  ObjectID     UserID  Description                 Email             Name
0     Ajh1    john123  Strawberry1      johnATjohnDOTcom      John Muller
1    Basd2   katie456      Orange1    katieATkatieDOTcom  Katherine Smith
2     Chg3   sarah789     Pumpkin1      saraATsaraDOTcom  Sara De La Cruz
3     Eas1    john123  Strawberry2      johnATjohnDOTcom      John Muller
4     Fjd3   sarah789     Pumpkin2      saraATsaraDOTcom  Sara De La Cruz
5     Gar2   katie456      Orange2    katieATkatieDOTcom  Katherine Smith
6     Dfd4  emilio012       Melon1  emilioATemilioDOTcom     Emilio Perez
7    Ddfd5  emilio012       Melon2  emilioATemilioDOTcom     Emilio Perez
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, sara->sarah

I had to switch the left and right (I've also anonymized this data, so I'm not sure which step along the process I've screwed that up) but it looks like it's working now.